# Renaming a File via FTP on C# program

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ftp

Hi I'm having a problem on my C# program when I try to rename a file on a ftp site. It returns an error while performing the renaming process. But it can download the file that I try to rename as well as I can upload a file on the ftp server so I guess it's not about permission.

I also try to do it on command prompt using the same login that I used in my program and I didn't encounter any error. I successfully rename any file on it.

The error message is like this:

> The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).

Here is my code for renaming the file:

```
public void rename(string currentFileNameAndPath, string newFileName)
{
    try
    {
        /* Create an FTP Request */
        ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(host + "/" + currentFileNameAndPath);
        /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        /* When in doubt, use these options */
        ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
        ftpRequest.UsePassive = false;
        ftpRequest.KeepAlive = false;
        ftpRequest.Proxy = null;
        /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename;
        /* Rename the File */
        ftpRequest.RenameTo = newFileName;
        /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
        ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
        /* Resource Cleanup */
        ftpResponse.Close();
        ftpRequest = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); 
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: This could be a few things. It may well be that you don't have permissions to rename (modify) the file but have read permissions. Also have you checked that the paths to the current and new filename baing called in the function are actually constructed properly and are valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I decided to just move the files into a new directory instead of renaming it since my goal from the start is to avoid overriding the original file when I upload a new file.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an error trying to rename a file on an AS400 server: 'Syntax error in parameters or arguments'.

My problem was that I filled in the `.RenameTo` property with a full URI.  Even shortening it to the folder path gave the same error.  Since I did not want to move the file but just rename it, this worked for me:

```
string fileToMove = "ftp://127.0.0.1/Folder1/File.csv";
string renamedFile = "FileRenamed.old";

FtpWebRequest ftpRenameFile = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fileToMove);
ftpRenameFile.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

ftpRenameFile.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename;
ftpRenameFile.RenameTo = renamedFile;   
ftpRenameFile.UseBinary = false;
ftpRenameFile.UsePassive = true; 

FtpWebResponse renameResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRenameFile.GetResponse();
```

The renamed file stays in the same directory.

Answer (score -1):

I've got the same error. I think your source file have got subfolders. These subfolders you have to remove in the target folder.